# What's the canonical way to make the directory that has the current source file to be searched by `use` and `require` statements in Perl in mod_perl?

Tags: perl, runtime, require, mod-perl

I tried

```
BEGIN {
    unshift @INC, 'current_path_string';
}
```

But it only works for `use`, when `require`, it's not searched.

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 4):

When running under mod_perl, once the server is up `@INC` is frozen and cannot be updated. The only opportunity to temporarily modify `@INC` is while the script or the module are loaded and compiled for the first time. After that its value is reset to the original one. The only way to change `@INC` permanently is to modify it at Apache startup.

Two ways to alter `@INC` at server startup:

- In the configuration file. e.g `PerlSetEnv PERL5LIB /home/httpd/perl`
- In the startup file directly alter the `@INC` and load the startup file from the configuration file.

See also [@INC and mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/porting.html#_INC_and_mod_perl)

Comment: Actually I don't want to make it permanent.That's why I `unshift @INC` inside `BEGIN`. But it doesn't work for `require` statements.

Comment: @new_perl It doesn't work for `require` because `require` happens at run time, after `@INC` is reset

Comment: but why it works this way: `BEGIN{unshift @INC, '/root/'} print "@INC";` ?? `/root/` is still there at run time.

Comment: @new_perl: It's a temporary modification, which mod_perl doesn't honor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can update @INC in the startup script. But using the code below in your module will simply work:

```
use lib '/app/my-libs';
```

at least - for my CGI app running under mod_perl.

Answer (score -1):

```
use Foo;
```

is the same as

```
BEGIN {
    require Foo;
    import Foo;
}
```

so if it works for `use`, it works for `require`.